# how to get the response of a command or shell script from a remote machine in Java code

Tags: linux, shell, java

I want to execute a set of Linux commands on a remote machine from Java code and I need to get the response of the commands to be printed in Java console. Can anyone provide me such API with a detailed example code as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some implementations:

- [SSHTools/j2ssh](https://www.sshtools.com/en/products/j2ssh)
- [Apache Mina](http://mina.apache.org/sshd-project/)
- [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/)